# Adding a script tag inside Azure B2C customized login HTML page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure B2C authentication in my react app and I've had a customized HTML on the blob storage and uploaded it on the portal. Everything seems to be working fine. However, I've added a script tag in the body of the HTML page to run some customized javascript functions but it looks like Azure removes all external script tags in both header and body. Is there a way to run my javascript code inside the HTML somehow or another?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable javascript in your custom policy or user flow. Guidance is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow).